# Increase setInterval time over time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm using this code to run a function every x seconds as long as there are no mouse movements or keys pressed. How can I increase the timer with 2x the value for every round as long as there is no user activity and cap it at 300000?

This is what I have so far, but I guess I need to actually get my time variable into the the setInterval again as it's been updated.

```
var idleTime = 0;
var time = 5000;
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
        time = 5000;
    });
    $(this).on('keypress', function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
        time = 5000;
    });
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, time);
});

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 1) {
        time = time*2;
        if( time > 300000 ) { time = 300000; }
        refreshContent();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use setTimeout, and at the end of the timeout function, call setTimeout again with the new value, basically it is similar to a recursive function.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Thanks, do you have an example of how that could look like?

Comment: either use the timeout and increase the delay variable, or just clear the interval and restart it with the desired delay each time it finishes. The first one is probably the cleverest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code to this, I think this is what you need see console after running (don't move your mouse it will reset timer),

```js
var time = 5000;
var idleInterval;
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, time);
    
    $(this).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
        time = 5000;
     clearInterval(idleInterval);
     idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, time);
    });
    $(this).on('keypress', function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
        time = 5000;
     clearInterval(idleInterval);
     idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, time);
    });
});

function timerIncrement() {

    console.log('refreshContent is called after '+time+' milliseconds');
    refreshContent();

    time = time*2;
    if( time > 300000 ) { time = 300000; }
    clearInterval(idleInterval);
    idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, time);
} 
function refreshContent()
{
    console.log('Stuffs you want to do when refresh content is called');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a timeout, and increase the timeout and then call the timeout again like below.

In the below example we call the timeout in 500ms, then we double it, to get called again at 1000ms, double that to 2000ms, and so on.

#### Edit

I am not exactly sure how you want it to work, but adding your jQuery to the mix, would look something like this. Once you `mousemove`, the timeout stops, once you stop moving the timeout starts back at `500ms`

```js
let timeout
let interval = 500
let maxTime = 10000

function myTimeout() {
      console.log("Delayed: " + interval + "ms")
      interval *= 2
      if(interval < maxTime) {
            timeout = setTimeout(myTimeout, interval)
      } else {
            console.log("I am exiting!")
      }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        clearTimeout(timeout)
        interval = 500
        timeout = setTimeout(myTimeout, interval)
    });
    $(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
        clearTimeout(timeout)
        interval = 500
        timeout = setTimeout(myTimeout, interval)
    });
    
    // Start the Timeouts
    timeout = setTimeout(myTimeout, interval)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas how I can get my mouse and key events in here?

Comment: does clearTimeout actually do anything in this case?  It doesn't look like its actually doing anything .  clearTimeout would take a timeOutId as a parameter right?

Comment: @SeaBass I updated the answer to address your question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't set setTimeout to a variable. It passes you the handle(basically the uniqueId of the timeout.).EDIT: You can use that Id to clear that specific timeout.

On your example, you can use this:

```
var idleTime = 0;
var time = 5000;
var currentActiveTimeoutId = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
        time = 5000;
        //reset timeout counter
        setTimeoutCounter(time);
    });
    $(this).on('keypress', function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
        time = 5000;
        //reset timeout counter
        setTimeoutCounter(time);
    });
    setTimeoutCounter(time);
});

//function to set the timeout and call the incrementor
function setTimeoutCounter(timeOut){
  //clear previous timeout created
  clearTimeout(currentActiveTimeoutId);
  currentActiveTimeoutId = setTimeout(timerIncrement, timeOut);
}

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 1) {
        time = time*2;
        if( time > 300000 ) { time = 300000; }
        refreshContent();
        //recall set timeout and apply the next value of time
        setTimeoutCounter(time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can assign it a variable, `setTimeout` returns a number, which is used to `clearTimeout`

Comment: Thanks! I think this is close. But the mouse and keyevents are creating 5 billion timers. Any way to reset the current one or remove the previous ones?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, yes. I completely forgot about that functionality. Will edit.

Comment: @SeaBass updated the answer with a possible way on how to clear it. Basically, what we do is we get the previous set timeout, clear it, then create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example with `mousemove` and `keypress` events.

reset when `mousemove` and `keypress` triggered (or max time reached)

```js
const init_time = 500;  //init time
const final_max = 5000; //max time
var myTimeout;

$(document).ready(function() {
  //event
  $(this).on('mousemove keypress', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
    myTimer(init_time);
  });
  //init
  myTimer(init_time);
});

function myTimer(period) {
  if (period >= final_max) {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
  } else {
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("myTimer -> " + period);
      myTimer(period * 2);
    }, period);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```